How to find the matrix $A$ from $C_0=A \times B$ or $C_1=B \times A$, given the singluar matrix B.
Kindly help me in the following:

Let $C_0=A \times B$ and  $C_1=B \times A$, where $A$ is a full rank square matrix, $B$ is a non-zero singular square matrix. Entries in $A,B,C$ are from finite integer field.

Known $(B,C_0,C_1)$, how to calculate the matrix $A$?


I have known that the matrices $(B,C_0,C_1)$ are all singular, there would be no unique solution for the matrix $A$. Even so, I want to find an approximate solution $A'$, such that $A'^{-1}\times C_0=B$ and  $C_0 \times A'^{-1}=B$.
So, could you help me to find a method to achieve this? Thank you.

Are these square matrices ?

@TedBlack Yes, they are square matrices.

If $B$ is the zero matrix, then you get no information about $A$ at all.

@GerryMyerson $B$ is non zero square matrix.

Well, now it is – it wasn't when I posted my comment. Still, if $B$ has only one nonzero entry, there's not much you can say about $A$, is there?

@GerryMyerson what I mean is to seek for some general methods to find the correct $A'$, s.t. $A'^{-1} \times C_0 = B$.

What I mean is that if $B$ has only one nonzero entry then there will be many matrices $A$ satisfying your equations, and no clear reason to prefer one of them to the others. Or, think of what happens if $B$ is the all ones matrix.

@GerryMyerson But a fact confused me is that you can pick a matrix $A'$ meeting $A' \times B=C_0$, which implies $A'^{-1} \times C_0 = B$, further meaning that $A'^{-1}=A^{-1}$. However, $A$'s inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ is unique, then $A'=A$.

You can pick a million different matrices $A$ meeting $A\times B=C_0$, and then you get a million different matrices $A^{-1}$ such that $A^{-1}\times C_0=B$. example: suppose $B=\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr0&0&0\cr0&0&0\cr}$, $C_0=\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr4&0&0\cr7&0&0\cr}$, $C_1=\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr0&0&0\cr0&0&0\cr}$. Then all you can say about $A$ is $A=\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr4&a&b\cr7&c&d\cr}$, where each of the numbers $a,b,c,d$ can be anything at all. A four-dimensional space of acceptable values for $A$!

@GerryMyerson Thanks a lot, I got your idea.

I would use a polar decomposition of $B=UDV$ where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices and $D=\mathrm{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_r,0,\ldots,0)$ with
$D_1=\mathrm{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_r)$ invertible.
Denote by blocks $r\times r $ etc
$$AU=\left[\begin{array}{cc}a_0&b_0\\c_0&d_0\end{array}\right],\ VA=\left[\begin{array}{cc}a_1&b_1\\c_1&d_1\end{array}\right], A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}a_2&b_2\\c_2&d_2\end{array}\right].$$ From $V^TC_0=AU D$ then $a_0,c_0$ are known, as $a_2,c_2$. From $C_1U^T= DVA$ then $a_0,b_0$ are known, as $a_2,b_2$. The matrices  $d_0$ and $d_1$ are arbitrary, but must fit for providing the same $d_2.$
